# Grave accent char ` causes an error an when is minified

Tags: javascript, minify

I want to minify my javascript but I have this error due to special chars used in multi line strings:

```
var string = `hello`;
```

This char ` is known as **Grave accent*

Result:

[image]

I tried several web tools and I had the same errors:

- http://beautifytools.com/javascript-minifier.php
- https://www.minifier.org/
- https://html-css-js.com/js/compressor/

## Question

How can I replace this character so that it can be minified?

I will try with some shell tool at the moment.

Thanks

## Updated

This is a more real snippet:

```
var cssText = `
position:absolute;
width:500px;
height:${some_var}px;
top:60px;
left:35px;
color:greenyellow;
padding: 5px;
`;
```

Comment: Why are you enclosing a string with accent grave characters?

Comment: Not a programming question, but about online tools.

Comment: @xehpuk I think is  related to programming. If I use other programming tools, the error is probably the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple tools that seem to do what you want

- https://codebeautify.org/minify-js
- https://minify.js.org/js/